# Command in $PATH not found

Tags: terminal, bash

I've created a symlink using:

```
sudo ln -s ~/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert /usr/local/bin
```

I can see the command `ebook-convert` in `/usr/local/bin`.

Then I've added `/usr/local/bin` in my $PATH. I can see it when doing `echo $PATH`.

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

But I still can't use `ebook-convert` from terminal and I get the error:

`-bash: ebook-convert: command not found`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

To analyze problems like that it helps to

- check whether the target of the symlink exists (`ls -l ~/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert`)
- check whether the target is executable
- verify whether the shell sees the file in question (`type ebook-convert`)

Doing so made me realize that Calibre was installed in `/Applications` instead of `~/Applications`.